# Multiple condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataset and contain price and currency. There are 3 currency dollar, euro, azn and it has 25000 columns. How to make price in azn currency I must multiply all dollar prices to 1.7 and euros to 1.9. I use where in pandas but I can do one of them as this:

```
df['price_new'] = df.price.where(df.currency=='AZN', df.price*1.7)
```

but this code works for only one condition and change only dollar to azn.

Comment: I advise against using `.`/attribute style for column access. Why are you using `.where()` for this, isn't it just a basic conditional operation? In any case I'm voting to close this since there's no reason why you can't repeat that same operation multiple times, and this sort of question can usually be answered by reading the docs.

Comment: @AMC: If you know which docs to read, please give a link, or quote them.

Comment: @9000 Sorry, I meant the Pandas docs themselves.

Comment: @AMC: Indeed! If you have an idea of the answer, just give it. If you know a good answer here on SO, link it, maybe it's a duplicate question. Otherwise, this question remains legitimate, to my mind.

Comment: @9000 I guess [Essential basic functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `np.select`

```
con1=df.currency=='AZN'
con2=...
v1=df.price*1.7
v2=...
df['price_new'] = np.select([con1,con2],[v1,v2])
```